# Separating and comparing complete cases and NA elements in a vector

Tags: r, nan

I have a vector with numerical and NA elements.
For example,

```
data<-c(.4, -1, 1, NA, 8, NA, -.4)
data[complete.cases(data), ]
```

But what's the function to separate them into different vectors so I can compare them using graphs such as a boxplot and ECDF?

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve. `complete.cases` creates a logical vector for selection (if you use it correctly.) You can negate it to get the other ones. You cannot address a vector as you attempted with `[ , ]` but if 'data' were a dataframe (or a matrix) that would have worked.

```
data<-c(.4, -1, 1, NA, 8, NA, -.4)
data[complete.cases(data) ]
#[1]  0.4 -1.0  1.0  8.0 -0.4
data[!complete.cases(data) ]
#[1] NA NA
```

If one is trying to select the non-NA items it might be easier to use `!is.na(data)` as the selection vector. This is a test case showing it works with matrices as well as data.frames:

```
> dat <- matrix( sample(c(1,2,NA), 12, rep=TRUE), 3)
> dat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]   NA   NA    2    2
[3,]    1   NA    2    1
> dat[ complete.cases(dat), ]
[1] 1 1 1 1
> dat[ ! complete.cases(dat), ]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA    2    2
[2,]    1   NA    2    1
```

Comment: Basically, I have a matrix, with data as the sub-matrix. I want to remove all NA values from both the matrix and sub-matrix, and then compare the values.

Comment: OK. Should work. But if this isn't the answer you need to provide a concrete case.

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by "compare values" .  Can you provide a small, reproducible example of your matrices?